# equals on collection views Java

Tags: java, maps, freeze

Do you understand in this slides what actually [this MIT course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-java-preparation-for-6-170-january-iap-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf) (The slide in question is at page 44) is talking about? What do they mean with Freeze keys? I understand that the keys of the map cannot be changed, otherwise both key and value will be lost. However I did not quite get the concept of freezing a key with the `boolean frozen`. (I have read only the slides freely downloadable on line, I did not attend the course)

```
//Freeze Keys
public class Name {
private
String first;
private
String last;
private
boolean frozen = false;

public void setFirst(String s) {
if (!frozen)
first = s;
}
//...
// do same with setLast
public void freeze() {
frozen = true;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you understand? no. explain in brief, we cant go through all this.

Comment: @ay89 tnx a lot for your support, have a nice day.

Comment: As far as I understood, a `boolean` is made use of to control and know if a variable could be set or not. This is more like their previous example of declaring the fields `final` and assigning values in the Constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`freeze` is just a flag that tells the class to *effectively* ignore calls to its setters by skipping over the variable assignment.

After you create an instance, calls to `setFirst` will set the `first` member variable.  After you call `freeze`, calls to `setFirst` will do nothing, thus "freezing" the state of the object.

Comment: A small correction: the flag tells the class whether to ignore the variable assignment.

Comment: Good point.  I edited the answer to be more precise.